# Screenshot in a small part of Qt-Window

Tags: qt, screenshot

I would like to be able to take screenshots of my program and save them as png (or if it is possible as pdf). I have taken the screenshot-example from Qt. This takes a screenshot from the whole display. But I would like to take a screenshot from only a part of my window, even if it is in another postion of the display. How can I do that. Is there a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` function [`grabWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWidget) of `QPixmap` is your friend. You can easily take a pixmap of the provided widget and then save it in any format you desire:

```
QPixmap p = QPixmap::grabWidget(widget);
p.save("p.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `QWidget::render` (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#render)?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the window to get it's position and size. If you have any specific element you want to see in the screenshot, you can get it's position and size instead. Otherwise, you'll have to use offsets from the window position which can cause trouble (for example, when the window is resized).

Get the screenshot and then crep the pixmap using the position/size from before.

There is one drawback: Taking a snapshot of the whole desktop is somewhat slow.

So a better solution might be to change your application: Render the parts you want to save in an off-screen buffer. You can then use this buffer to render the UI and save the screenshot at the same time.